# Create Custom Fields Programmatically combining Textview and EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, advanced-custom-fields, programmatically-created

I'm working on making dynamic form from the Strings received from JSON Response of the API.

Here I want to create a dynamic form where I want to identify **{field_name}** and replace it into EditText.

String given below is a string received from the API Response and yes it contains **"{}"** as a part of string.

So I am finding for them with the help of **while loop** and creating EditText for each time that a {} is found.

Now the problem that I am not able to resolve is how to append those EditText with the String/TextView.

For Example,

```
String demo = "{event_name} Event on{event_date} at {event_time} venue {event_venue} All are welcome. -";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

EditText et;

while (m.find()) {
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, 
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
   et = new EditText(this);
   Log.e("onCreateInternal: ", "=" + i);

   SmsTypeGroup.addView(et, lp)
}
```

After Replacing the **{}** with EditText from the String the desired output is as below.

[Required output is as shown in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIM5U.png)

Any Help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**Note: The Only condition is that the whole process is to be done programmatically from Java file, no use of XML.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i gather english is not your first language, but if i understand correctly, what you are getting right now is just a view with 4 editText, and you need a way to additionally add textviews with the text inbetween the {} elements in the string.

one way to do this would be to use split instead of the patternmatch:

```
String demo = "{event_name} Event on{event_date} at {event_time} venue {event_venue} All are welcome. -";
String[] parts = demo.split("}");

EditText et;

for(String part : parts){
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
   et = new EditText(this);

   SmsTypeGroup.addView(et, lp);

   String[] _parts = part.split("{");
   if(_parts.length >1){
     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.text = _parts.[0];
     SmsTypeGroup.addView(tv, lp)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. WIth minor changes it is the perfect answer for my problem.

Comment: happy to help:)